# How to catch and return errors in Laravel controller after validation?

Tags: validation, laravel-5.7, error-messaging

I'm using this code to validate my `$request` variable:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'string|required|max:255',
    'lead' => 'nullable|string',
    ...
]);
```

After this I want to return error messages as a JSON object, use this code:

```
return response()->json([
    'errors' => $validatedData->errors()
]);
```

And here it says `$ValidateData` is an array. That's true, but where can I find the validation error messages? I checked the official Laravel 5.7 documentation, but it's not clear.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need customoize the error messages, just need to read this in laravel documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#customizing-the-error-messages
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#working-with-error-messages

```
$messages = [
    'same'    => 'The :attribute and :other must match.',
    'size'    => 'The :attribute must be exactly :size.',
    'between' => 'The :attribute value :input is not between :min - :max.',
    'in'      => 'The :attribute must be one of the following types: :values',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

I hope, i could help for you.